# iOS app launches to black view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I have been trying to run my Xcode project on my iOS simulator an iPhone but I only get a black screen. I have tried multiple solutions but none seem to work.

I have tried:

1. Setting main interface to "Main.storyboard"
2. Installing all views i.e.: width: any, height: any
3. Adding print statement to `viewDidLoad` to state that the view did in fact load (didn't print that the view loaded)
4. Resetting all content of the iOS simulator
5. Running on my iPhone
6. Setting initial view controller

None of these have solved my problem

Comment: Do you have a view controller in the storyboard designated as the initial view controller?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I didn't add that @ThePumpingLama

Comment: Not much to go on. Please add the code code from your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. Also, the fact that the initial view controller is not loading (I assume that is where your `print` is located?) is odd so check that if you create a new blank app you can run that in the simulator (so you've checked the simulator works). If it does, the there could be an issue with your storyboard.

Comment: Make sure in your AppDelegate that you are creating the variable window like so (right after the app delegate class declaration): `var window: UIWindow?`

Comment: Oh shoot I think that might be it! Thanks so much @JohnRamos

Comment: @HarryMerzin Glad I could help; this happened to me once :D. I added this as an answer, please upvote it if it indeed helps or comment below if it didn't help!

Comment: @JohnRamos I had to start a new project because nothing seemed to be working but i do think that that was the solution so I'll up vote and add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure in your AppDelegate that you are creating the variable window like so (right after the app delegate class declaration): `var window: UIWindow?`.

Without this line of code, your views will just never launch and your screen will stay black.

Answer (score 1):

There might be many reasons for  blank black view. But first check whether you have the window variable declared in your appDelegate as suggested by @john. If this doesnt work, check in the storyboard whether you have made your first controller as initial view controller.

You can also do this by adding rootviewController as the view controller you want in the window inside `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: The asker said he tried "setting the initial view controller."

Answer (score 0):

May be you use an empty UIViewController(). In my case I set a default value an empty UIViewController()